# DAG construction fails when using remote providers without internet connection

Tags: snakemake

I'm using [remote providers](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/remote_files.html#read-only-web-http-s) with `snakemake`, in my case the ones for HTTP(S).

When I run the workflow on a machine with internet access, everything works fine.

*Problem*

If I run the workflow and all remote files are locally present, and then transfer the workflow and its files to another machine without internet access (HPC cluster), `snakemake` fails[^1] already during the DAG construction process while trying to access the internet for the rules using a remote provider.

*Question*:

Is there a way to use Snakemake in this situation and just tell it to use the locally existing file versions?

*I tried*

- Marking the files `ancient(...)`
- Setting `--rerun-trigger mtime`

*Current workaround*

My current workaround is to make a conditional include in the `Snakefile` to only include rules using remote providers an Python can resolve and connect to the URL.

*Footnotes*

[^1] I get time outs or errors that the remote URL cannot be resolved - depending on which system I test it on and how internet access is restricted.

*edit*

Example `Snakefile` looks like this:

```py
from shutil import copyfile, move

from snakemake.remote.HTTP import RemoteProvider as HTTPRemoteProvider
HTTP = HTTPRemoteProvider()

rule retrieve_cost_data:
    input:
        HTTP.remote(
            "raw.githubusercontent.com/PyPSA/technology-data/v0.5.0/outputs/costs_{year}.csv",
            keep_local=True,
        ),
    output:
        "data/costs_{year}.csv",
    run:
        move(input[0], output[0])

rule use_cost_data:
    input:
        "data/costs_2030.csv"
    output:
        "resources/costs.csv"
    default_target:
        True
    run:
        copyfile(input[0], output[0])
```

And locally present files are:

```bash
> tree
.
├── Snakefile
├── data
│   └── costs_2030.csv
└── resources
```

With internet connection DAG is properly constructed:

```bash
> snakemake -call -n                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
Building DAG of jobs...
Job stats:
job              count    min threads    max threads
-------------  -------  -------------  -------------
use_cost_data        1              1              1
total                1              1              1


[Thu Jul 13 09:08:38 2023]
rule use_cost_data:
    input: data/costs_2030.csv
    output: resources/costs.csv
    jobid: 0
    reason: Missing output files: resources/costs.csv
    resources: tmpdir=/tmp

Job stats:
job              count    min threads    max threads
-------------  -------  -------------  -------------
use_cost_data        1              1              1
total                1              1              1

Reasons:
    (check individual jobs above for details)
    missing output files:
        use_cost_data

This was a dry-run (flag -n). The order of jobs does not reflect the order of execution.
```

Running without an internet connection the DAG construction fails:

```bash
> snakemake -call -n
Building DAG of jobs...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 174, in _new_conn
    conn = connection.create_connection(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 72, in create_connection
    for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.11/socket.py", line 962, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
socket.gaierror: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 703, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 386, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 1042, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 363, in connect
    self.sock = conn = self._new_conn()
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 186, in _new_conn
    raise NewConnectionError(
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f9324605010>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.11/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 489, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 787, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 592, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='raw.githubusercontent.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /PyPSA/technology-data/v0.5.0/outputs/costs_2030.csv (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f9324605010>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.11/site-packages/snakemake/__init__.py", line 757, in snakemake
    success = workflow.execute(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.11/site-packages/snakemake/workflow.py", line 745, in execute
    dag.init()
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.11/site-packages/snakemake/dag.py", line 207, in init
    job = self.update([job], progress=progress, create_inventory=True)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.11/site-packages/snakemake/dag.py", line 877, in update
    self.update_(
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.11/site-packages/snakemake/dag.py", line 992, in update_
    selected_job = self.update(
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.11/site-packages/snakemake/dag.py", line 877, in update
    self.update_(
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.11/site-packages/snakemake/dag.py", line 981, in update_
    if not res.file.exists:
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.11/site-packages/snakemake/io.py", line 449, in exists
    return self.exists_remote
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.11/site-packages/snakemake/io.py", line 243, in wrapper
    v = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.11/site-packages/snakemake/io.py", line 470, in exists_remote
    return self.remote_object.exists()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.11/site-packages/snakemake/remote/HTTP.py", line 159, in exists
    with self.httpr(verb="HEAD") as httpr:
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.11/contextlib.py", line 137, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.11/site-packages/snakemake/remote/HTTP.py", line 152, in httpr
    r = requests.head(url, *args_to_use, **kwargs_to_use)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.11/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 100, in head
    return request("head", url, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.11/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 59, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.11/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 587, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.11/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 701, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.11/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 565, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='raw.githubusercontent.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /PyPSA/technology-data/v0.5.0/outputs/costs_2030.csv (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f9324605010>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the `--forceall` option? The command-line would look like this:

```bash
snakemake -j 1 --forceall --dag | dot -Tpdf > dag.pdf
```

Comment: Tried it, the result is the same: DAG cannot be resolved. I've added an example above.